# Make Eclipse Sirius plugin or Eclipse Rich Client Platform

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-sirius

I made Eclipse Sirius Tutorials (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials) and now I would like to make standalone application with prepared Sirius runtime.

Is there any way to run it standalone? I don't want to run one instance of Eclipse and in this instance another instance with Sirius Runtime.

Maybe I can make plugin for Eclipse and use it? Or make Eclipse Rich Client Platform?

Comment: prepare a jar for your application, and include all required jars in the same folder and run : `java -cp <path_to_folder_with_jars> -jar <your_sirius_jar>`

Comment: but how can i make jar from .odesign file ?

Comment: Isn't your Sirius application a plugin?

Comment: it is a plugin, I made only tutorial application

Comment: If there is a plugin, you should be able to build a jar out of it. You can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119677/how-do-i-automatically-generate-a-jar-file-in-an-eclipse-java-project)

Comment: I create jar by "File" -> "Export" -> "JAR File". but when I try run it by *java -cp <path_to_folder_with_jars> -jar <your_sirius_jar>* as you adwise but i get error "no main manifest attribute, in test.jar". I have MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF folder so i don't understand what is wrong

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: Ok, but I don't know wich class have main method in sirius application

Comment: You should be able to identify the main class in MANIFEST.MF

Comment: But it not just simple java application with main class. This is eclipse plugin (i think so). So there isn't maib class :(

Comment: it's the same as building an eclipse RCP application, it's just an additional dependencies with sirius, that's all. I suggest that you search tutorial for ways of building eclipse RCP application (through product file, or maven)

Comment: @flafoux do you know any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an [Eclipse product](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_an_Eclipse_product%3F). This product will reference other plugins and features and it will let you create a complete package for your application. You can add or remove menu, customize the branding of the product with a splash screen, an icon etc.

Have a look at the [product and branding](https://github.com/dartdesigner/Dart-Designer/tree/master/packaging) of [Dart Designer](http://dartdesigner.github.io) for a Sirius stand alone application