# Add jar source to main project

Tags: eclipse

In my workspace, I have my main project and it uses several jars. I need to make changes in one of the jars. I added the source for that jar to my workspace and I make the change, create a new jar at the command line, copy it over to my main project, bounce app server and try it out. Is there a way to instead point my project at the jar source rather than the jar file? I'd expect to change the jar source, Eclipse would auto build like it does my main project, and I'd only have to restart my app server to test.

Comment: Possibly related:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062941/build-project-into-a-jar-automatically-in-eclipse?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add external jars, then you can build the jar, safe it somewhere accessible by your app server and restart the server, it will use the new jar and everything should be fine.

For a bigger scope there are many solutions using maven for example to build more then one Project at a time and merge them like needed, but that would be to much for a single jar.